# $\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {\sin x-\sqrt {3}\cos x}{\sin 3x}$ has two different values?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Given a limit like:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {\sin x-\sqrt {3}\cos x}{\sin 3x}$$

How did I solve it:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2 (-\frac {1}{2}\sin x+\frac {\sqrt {3}}{2}\cos x)}{\sin 3x} &= \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2 (-\sin\frac {\pi}{6}\sin x+\cos \frac {\pi}{6}\cos x)}{\sin 3x}\\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2\cos (\frac{\pi }{6}+x)}{\sin 3x}\\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2\cos (\frac{\pi }{6}+x)}{\sin 3x}\\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2\cos \left[\frac{\pi }{2}-(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)\right]}{\sin 3x}\\&= \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{3}}\frac {-2\sin (\frac{\pi}{3}-x)}{\sin 3x}\\&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac {-2\sin t}{\sin \left[3 (\frac{\pi}{3}-t)\right]}\\&= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac {-2\sin t}{-\sin 3t}\\&= \frac {2}{3}\end{align}$$

I don't know if this is correct but Wolfram Alpha points out it's $-\frac {2}{3}$ instead (L'hopital Rules).
Can anyone show me if there's any error above? Or the limit really has two answers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: NO; if the *limit* exists, it is unique.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA (in reals :))

Comment: @user251257 In $\mathbb{C}$, and etc. The true answer for the question in the title is that the space is Hausdorff.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if I use different trig identities, they lead to different answers, yes?

Comment: "if I use different trig identities, they lead to different answers, yes?" NO: if you compute a sum with different methods the result **must** be the same, otherwise the "sum" operation is not (well) defined.

Comment: Thanks, I was mistaken, myself.

Comment: @GNUSupporter  the 'epsilon-delta' definition of limit requires a metric space.  They are automatically Hausdorff

Comment: As a rule of thumb, Alpha is right and you are wrong.

Comment: @aginensky Yeah you're right, but IMHO, metric is not the main point.  OP asks *why* limit is unique.  Without metric, you can still define limits with topology.  The true reason should be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Can anyone show me if there's any error above?*

Your mistake:
$$
\sin 3 (\frac{\pi}{3}-t)=\color{red}{-}\sin 3t
$$ instead of
$$
\sin\left[ 3 \left(\frac{\pi}{3}-t\right)\right]=\sin 3t.
$$ (one may recall that $\cos (3\pi)=-1$)